# Is there an active nightlife in Seoul on weekdays?

Tags: south-korea, nightlife, seoul

I'll be traveling to Seoul on a Monday in the near future and I want to experience the nightlife culture. My concern is that I leave Seoul on a Friday afternoon and unable to experience the nightlife. I searched on various traveling sites and everyone recommends experience on a Friday and Saturday, which is understandable. 
Is it still possible to experience the nightlife Monday-Thursday or is it non-existent?

Comment: There isn't that much nightlife outside the weekend, almost anywhere.

Comment: Is that from personal experience?

Comment: It exists , but less intensive than on weekdays. and having a Local friend is what you need because it actually exists on the less touristy and less known places.

Comment: @MichaelHampton there's *always* something going on in London, for example. I assume Seoul is the same.

Comment: I assume the closer I am to the weekend the better it is. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'd go a step further and say that almost all the *good* London nightlife is on weekdays; on weekends unless you can find somewhere most people don't know about yet, almost everywhere becomes all about charging drunks £15 to stand wedged in each other's armpits...

Answer (score 3):

There is always something going on but like mentioned typically less so on weekdays unless you are well acquainted with a local or maybe not foreign. I've seen some clubs in Seoul popping on a weekday but they were clubs for Koreans only.
My general rule of thumb is, Thursday-Sunday is always a good bet. Monday and Tuesday can be a little less lively. Wednesday is a wildcard. But Mon-Wed there will still be some heads out. I want to say that there is never downtime when it comes to nightlife in Seoul. It could just be the places I've frequented.

Comment: When you say "clubs for Koreans only" do you mean a non-Korean would actually get turned away at the door and not allowed in? Or that 99%+ of people there are Korean and you won't have a good time unless you can speak the language and fit in?

Comment: @user568458 actually yes, in some places you will get turned away if you are a non-Korean. With that said there are a few places where it is only foreigners allowed. It is just their homogeneous culture. I haven't found much on how useful speaking Korean helps in this situation. I was surprised when I found this out through searching nightlife in various areas.

Comment: @user568458 it depends on which Korean vouches for you, but most of the time non-Korean's will be shown the door